# What is this rotating pipe adapter called

Tags: plumbing, pipe, valve, adapter

[image]

This is the solenoid valve from Orbit Water Timer I have. I want to know what is the rotating adapter on the right side called. I would want to buy one for some of the threaded taps that I have in my farm.

The adapter is great to connect to threaded male pipes. If anyone has Water Timer or some such, they should be able to identify clearly what I mean.

Is this something which can be easily purchased?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own about the products from the manufacturer before you came here to ask questions.  https://www.orbitonline.com/

Comment: it sounds kind of like you want a hose union.

Answer (score 2):

The fitting on the right side of the assembly in your picture is a **union**, it lets you make a threaded connection without spinning the whole assembly.  It's not just handy, it's essential because it lets you make a threaded connection where you cut into an existing system or when you're making complex assemblies that can't be built by spinning the pieces on sequentially one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for "**Swivel adapters**" if you mean connect to male **pipe threads**. Very common/handy for connecting PEX directly to faucet *inputs*, for instance

If you mean **garden hose threads** (a faucet *outlet* for certain types of faucet) that would be a different item.

It's not clear from the question what you mean, as it's not obvious what type of threads this item has internally or is intended to connect to.